# unix ksh how to print $1 and first n characters of $2

Tags: unix, awk, printing

I have a file as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/oratab  
hostname01:DBNAME11:/oracle_home/A_19.0.0.0:N
hostname01:DBNAME1_DC:/oracle_home/A_19.0.0.0:N
hostname02:DBNAME21:/oracle_home/B_19.0.0.0:N
hostname02:DBNAME2_DC:/oracle_home/B_19.0.0.0:N
```

I want print the unique of the first column, first 6 characters of the second column and the third column  when the third column matches the string "19.0.0".

The output I want to see is:

```
hostname01:DBNAME1:/oracle_home/A_19.0.0.0
hostname02:DBNAME2:/oracle_home/B_19.0.0.0
```

I put together this piece of code but looks like its not the correct way to do it.

```
cat /etc/oratab|grep "19.0.0"|awk '{print $1}' || awk -F":" '{print subsrt($2,1,8)}
```

sorry I am very new to shell scripting

Comment: You mean "first **7** characters of the second column", not "first 6...", right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} index($3,"19.0.0"){print $1, substr($2,1,7), $3}' file | sort -u
hostname01:DBNAME1:/oracle_home/A_19.0.0.0
hostname02:DBNAME2:/oracle_home/B_19.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** With your shown sample please try following, written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {$2=substr($2,1,7)} !arr[$1,$2]++ && $3~/19\.0\.0/{NF--;print}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** OR in case your `awk` doesn't support `NF--` then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=":"
}
{
  $2=substr($2,1,7)
}
!arr[$1,$2]++ && $3~/19\.0\.0/{
  $4=""
  sub(/:$/,"")
  print
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, set field separator and output field separator as `:`. Then in main program, set 2nd field to 1st 7 characters of its value. Then check condition if they are unique(didn't occur before) and 3rd field is like 19.0.0, reduce 1 field and print that line.

Comment: @codethirst, could you please do let me know if my answer has helped you?

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $3 ~ /19\.0\.0/ && !seen[$1]++ {
print $1, substr($2,1,7), $3}' /etc/fstab

hostname01:DBNAME1:/oracle_home/A_19.0.0.0
hostname02:DBNAME2:/oracle_home/B_19.0.0.0
```

We check and populate associative array `seen` only if we find `19.0.0` in `$3`.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines can be like this and ending on `19.0.0`

```
hostname01:DBNAME1:/oracle_home/A_19.0.0.0
hostname01:DBNAME1:/oracle_home/A_19.0.0.1
```

and the `hostname01` only should be unique, you might miss a line.

---

You could match the pattern using sed and use 2 capture groups that you want to keep and match what you don't want.

Then pipe the output to `uniq` to get all unique lines instead of line the first column.

```
sed -nE 's/^([^:]+:.{7})[^:]*(:[^:]*19\.0\.0[^:]*).*/\1\2/p' file | uniq
```

Output

```
hostname01:DBNAME1:/oracle_home/A_19.0.0.0
hostname02:DBNAME2:/oracle_home/B_19.0.0.0
```